# shake: Invalid statement: import Development.Shake

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

My first attempt using shake, tried to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/master/docs/Manual.md#readme

I copied the makefile verbatim and ran shake. Shake printed `shake: Invalid statement: import Development.Shake`. My first thought was that maybe a new version had been released where these import statements had been made redundant. So I commented them out and got `shake: Invalid statement: -- import Development.Shake`. So I removed them. Here was the output:

```
shake: Error when running Shake build system:
* main
* IO
Error, file does not exist and no rule available:
  IO
```

GHC compiles the makefile fine. I'm not really sure what else to do to debug (I'm far from a Haskell expert!).

Somewhat relatedly (to the tutorial, at least) `shake --demo` no longer seems to exist.

Comment: The --demo feature will be available in the next release. I hadn't realised I'd pushed the doc updates yet, sorry about that.

Comment: @NeilMitchell, don't worry about it, it's a bit funny. Thanks for responding, in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have preferred commenting instead of answering (I miss some reputation to do so). I apologize in advance if my "answer" is a bit off.

Have you followed the [running section of the tutorial](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/master/docs/Manual.md#running) ? Or have you tried it with runHaskell ?

I would suspect something is wrong with the way you try to run the example, not the code itself.

Comment: Indeed, I've misunderstood (and not read far enough). And here I'd hoped it wasn't a silly mistake. Thank you!